# Google Compute Engine-WARNING Could not create user admin

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-compute-engine

Launched Ubuntu 14.04 LTS standard image on GCE,Browser SSH returns failure on 3 attempts. The console output that interest me as below:

```
accounts-from-metadata: **WARNING Could not create user admin**
#012STDOUT:#012
#012STDERR:#012
useradd: group admin exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g.#012

Invalid user admin from xx.xx.xx.xx

input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
```

Note: it works on Debian image (standard) but not Ubuntu 12 or 14 LTS. Could it be GCE create user based on the email address i am logged in by design which is admin@xxx.com, and trying to create user "admin" while the image has existing user "admin" is causing this issue? How do i fix this?

I like the browser SSH feature not having to use Putty & prefer Ubuntu over Debian due to experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The username for SSH session from browser is generated from the email address logged into the account without the domain.

You can change the username by follow the steps as mentioned in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#login_username).

> You can change the username from within an SSH window, following these instructions:
>
> 1. Connect to a virtual machine instance.
> 2. In the top right-hand corner of the SSH window, click the Settings icon.
> 3. Select Change Linux Username.